# How to get all processes in a display from Xvfb?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, process, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I have a program that is launching ChromeDrivers, which launches Chrome browsers + later attempts to close both after doing some task (using Selenium). But often times my program can't kill off the ChromeDriver/Chrome browser. When I try to kill the ChromeDriver the Chrome browser + all it's other child processes aren't killed off.

I have tried to look at /proc/x/environ to determine if I can extract the DISPLAY of the process, but found that no such environment variable was set for the browser + child processes.

Is there any other way to detect all processes in a specific Xvfb display and kill them all?

Comment: Hello , can you please share your code so we can have a look at the problem.

Comment: That's not relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to kill all the driver instances after you are finished with you task?

Comment: Chrome was just the primary thing of concern, but is not limited to Chrome. I need a way to obtain all processes for a display in Xvfb.

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite promising if you only have one child process:

```bash
xvfb-run sleep 60 &
pid_xvfb=$!
kill $(ps -o pid= --ppid $pid_xvfb)
```